# cloud vision API for different API feature

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I am using the android sample of cloud vision API, I am getting a proper response for LABEL_DETECTION only, for any other like FACE_DETECTION or SAFE_SEARCH_DETECTION I am getting nothing in my response.
NOTE: I am using Browser key, the API key did not work.

I am changing the below code .setType LABEL_DETECTION to for example FACE_DETECTION, it is not working.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-vision/tree/master/android

```
                        // add the features we want
                    annotateImageRequest.setFeatures(new ArrayList<Feature>() {{
                        Feature labelDetection = new Feature();
                        labelDetection.setType("LABEL_DETECTION");
                        labelDetection.setMaxResults(10);
                        add(labelDetection);
                    }});
```

Any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You should override convertResponseToString method. At that example, he wrote `getLabelAnnotations()` which is for label results. You should call `getFaceAnnotations()`